# How to prevent ListView to set ViewModel.SelectedItem to null when DataTemplate unloads?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a screen with a ListView, with ItemsSource and SelectedItem bound to suitable properties in ViewModel.

This screen is part of a DataTemplate for the screen view model. The problem is: when I "navigate away" from this screen, `SelectedItem` property *in view model* is set to null, which is not what I want. Instead, I need the selection to be "remembered" so that when I navigate again to that screen, the last selected item is "still" selected.

If I understand right, the problem is that, when DataTemplate unloads (and so TheView unloads), it deselects the ListView and this is sent to ViewModel via the two-way binding, and I guess I should avoid that somehow.

I tried the following, it works, but feels hackish if not plain wrong:

```
// in TheSelectedItem setter
if (value == null)
    return;
```

Any suggestion?

Relevant code below:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveScreen}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TheViewModel}">
            <vw:TheView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OtherViewModel}">
            <vw:OtherView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AnotherViewModel}">
            <vw:AnotherView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

TheView.xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="TheViewSource"
        Source="{Binding TheItems}"
        Filter="someFilter"
    />
</UserControl.Resources>

        <ListView               
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TheViewSource}}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
        >
```

TheViewModel.xaml:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> TheItems { get; set; }

public ItemViewModel TheSelectedItem
{
    get { return _tsi; }
    set
    {
        _tsi = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => TheSelectedItem);
    }
}
ItemViewModel _tsi;
```

Comment: How do you set the ActiveScreen property? The selection should remain unless you create a new instance of TheViewModel/OtherViewModel/AnotherViewModel each time you navigate to it.

Comment: @mm8 ActiveScreen is an INPC property of type ViewModelBase, and the main View Model  has other properties for that type, which are long-lived. So when I want to change screen, I set `ActiveScreen` to the appropriate instance, which is already instantiated at the main View Model.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible sample of your issue. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided.